# Ansi c supports a ftp connection to transfer files from one pc to another?

Tags: c

i have a task to transfer text files from one pc to another using FTP , i need some directions how can it be done in ansi c as its user requirement to do it in ansi c

windows palte form so windows libs may also be used ..............

looking for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what platform do you use?

- On windows, have a look at the winsock library.
- on Unix, examine sockets library

Can you use an external library? then [this here](http://nbpfaus.net/~pfau/ftplib/) might come in handy.

Comment: Note all these point to an external library as ANSI-C does not cover anything to do with FTP. So you need another library